# Laravel eloquent many to many with conditions

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have `many to many` relationships. Let's say I am using `foo` and `bar`

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function bars() 
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Bar::class);
    }
}

class Bar extends Model
{
    public function foos() 
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Foo::class);
    }
}
```

how to show only `Foo` that have `Bar` so `Foo` record that not associated with `Bar` will not be displayed?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use has method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
$foos = App\Foo::has('bars')->get();
```

Comment: can i add conditions to bars?... like only `bars id = 1`